# Join a MS SQL Server WITH statement into a Select statement

Tags: sql-server

I received this answer to this question [MS SQL Server Last User Logged in Multiple Clients with Multiple Users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56704524/ms-sql-server-last-user-logged-in-multiple-clients-with-multiple-users) and it works great.

```
;with cte as
(
    select 
        client, myuser, lastlogin, 
        row_number() over (partition by client order by lastlogin desc) r# 
    from 
        @mytable 
)
select * 
from cte 
where r# = 1
```

How do I get this joined to a regular `Select` statement that selects data from other tables also?

For example:

```
 SELECT t1.id, t2.name
 FROM table1 t1
 JOIN table2 t2 ON (t2.id = t1.id)
 WHERE t1.id = 1
```

Comment: Just use it as any other table...

Comment: What would the SQL look like? I do not know how to make it one query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no restriction, you can just join a result of a cte with other tables. Cte is a subquery, but it makes your code more readable.

```
 ;with cte as(
 select client,myuser,lastlogin,row_number() over(partition by client order by lastlogin desc) r# 
 from @mytable 
)
 SELECT t1.id, t2.name
 FROM table1 t1
 JOIN table2 t2 ON (t2.id = t1.id)
 JOIN cte t3 ON (...)
 WHERE t1.id = 1
```

This is the same as a query with cte.

```
 SELECT t1.id, t2.name
 FROM table1 t1
 JOIN table2 t2 ON (t2.id = t1.id)
 JOIN ( select client,myuser,lastlogin,row_number() over(partition by client order by lastlogin desc) r# 
 from @mytable) t3 ON (...)
 WHERE t1.id = 1
```

Comment: Thank you, now it makes sense.